# How do I load a React component through a JavaScript UMD?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to use the following [external component](https://github.com/frontend-collective/react-image-lightbox) in my React project. My project is not based directly on the npm ecosystem (I am using react-dom), so I have been trying to import the component using a static compiled JavaScript file with a regular script tag in my html.

The file generated by the build seems to be a JavaScript UMD. I have tried to load this module using RequireJS, but I have been having the problem described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15371918/mismatched-anonymous-define-module).

I'm not really sure whether I am approaching this correctly. I know that Browserfy performs similar functions to RequireJS, but I'm not even certain whether I should be pursuing this as a possible avenue.

What is the canonical way to load a component like this into the browser?

This question may be a duplicate of this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46746776/how-do-i-import-a-react-component-through-a-html-script-tag), but it does not have any real answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For reference, I found that this can be done using existing libraries, such as https://github.com/revolunet/react-umd-loader . Even if the libraries themselves are somewhat deprecated, the techniques used are still relevant.